# cocoa login window navigation using button click

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, login-control

I am doing code in cocoa with objective c. I have made login window with username and password. I want to show another window using button click on login form. So user first input username and password and then click on submit button it will close this window and open new window with passing this username and password to that new window.

Kindly suggest how to do code ?

Thanks

Comment: Is login view is your initial view(First view). If so while clicking the login button then call local notification to AppDelegate from there you can dismiss login view and present your view as root view.

Comment: Below is my code...-(IBAction)btnSaveTapped:(id)sender {
    //Check inputs not null
    if( [txtUserName.stringValue isEqual: @""] || [txtpassword.stringValue isEqual: @""]) {
        NSData *plainData1 = [@"Enter valid username and password" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];        
        
    }
    else {
        
        
          // Move to Next Window open here 
            
            
        
    }
}

Comment: I am not getting your exact requirement. You want to pass the data from one view to another (or) close the current view and present second view as initial view. Passing data from one view to another view not a big matter. First tell me what is exact scenario.

Comment: I want to close the current view(window of login page) and view next view (window as webview)

Comment: If you are closing initial view controller, you have to make the second view as initial view controller. To do that in else condition you have to implement dismisviewController with block. In AppDeleagte declare local notification. Call that notification in dismiss block. After notification called then present your second view as initial view.

Comment: I am trying but not getting succes..can i have some ref. code/example

Comment: No. Right now I don't had the code. In my previous project I did that. you have to google for three things 1) how to use local notifications   2) how to call a method or notification before dismiss a view. 3) How to make view controller as initial view controller programatically. Google these definitely you will get the answers.

Comment: We are still in trouble..Raghu can you help me?

Comment: Handling View Controllers is a very basic thing. Show your approach after @PhaniRaghu hints.And please not as comment